# In WebSocket server running on CMD and client running on web

Tags: php, web, websocket, cmd, break

I created this one using WebSocket. server is  running on CMD and client running on web.

My problem was I want to change code, both server and client sides are working on web page. Like real time chatting app and also  want, when anyone type exit then server will be terminate.

### **Server(php)**

```
<?php

$host = "127.0.0.1";
$port = "20205";
set_time_limit(0);

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_bind($sock, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");

$result = socket_listen($sock, 3) or die("Could not setup socket listener\n");

class Chat {
    function readline() {
        return rtrim(fgets(STDIN));
    }
}

do {
    $accept = socket_accept($sock) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
    $msg    = socket_read($accept, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");

    $msg    = trim($msg);
    echo "Client Says:\t".$msg."\n\n";

    $line = new Chat();
    echo "Enter reply:\t";
    $reply=$line->readline();

    socket_write($accept, $reply, strlen($reply)) or die("Could not write output\n");
}while(true);

socket_close($accept, $sock);
```

?>

---

---

**Client(php)**

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center"></div>

    <form method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                     <label>Enter Message</label>
                     <input type="text" name="txtMessage">
                     <input type="submit" name="btnSend" value="Send">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $host ="127.0.0.1";
            $port ="20205";

            if(isset($_POST['btnSend'])){
                 $msg = $_REQUEST['txtMessage'];
                    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
                    socket_connect($sock, $host, $port);

                    socket_write($sock, $msg, strlen($msg));

                    $reply = socket_read($sock, 1924);
                    $reply = trim($reply);

                    $reply = "Server says:\t".$reply;

            }
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <textarea rows="10" cols="30"> <?php echo @$reply ; ?> </textarea> 
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: What exactly do you mean "running on web" anyway? You can't run a websocket server wtihin a browser, if that's what you mean. And what problem are you having, precisely? Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and then [edit] your question to make it comprehensible and explain a specific problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I corrected my mistakes. I'm sorry for that. and can you help me solve my problem?